# How to keep hair particles from moving

Tags: particles, hair

I don't know much about hair dynamics and using particles to create hair. I tried it once but my computer couldn't take it. Every time I hit play I would see the hair particles fall and move dynamically, and it would cause the speed to reduce drastically.

I came up with a character for whom I just want to have short fur that sticks to his body and doesn't move around. I don't want his fur to move in a wavelike motion or anything. Is there a way to create hair particles that don't move? They don't dangle or wave or anything but will still stay attached to the character?

Comment: What Blender version you use? By default "Hair Dynamics" is disabled ...

Comment: as Vklidu says, disable Hair Dynamics, also if hair particles are too heavy maybe use another method like planes with png image?

Comment: the easiest thing would be if you provide your blend file so we can check it out

Comment: So all you need to do is make sure hair dynamics is disabled? I'm using 2.97 so yeah it's disabled by default. If that's the case then I think that's all I need to know

Comment: Would be more helpful if you could try our recommendation and spend your previous comment to let us know if it worked.